# Why does the call to ObjectSet<T>.AddObject() get all entities of type T?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
var he = new LogHistoryEntry
             {
                 ActionId = action.Id,
                 ObjectId = logObject.Id,
                 UserId = user.Id,
                 Info = msg,
                 Item = s.Id,
                 Date = DateTime.Now
             };

ctx.LogHistoryEntries.AddObject(he);
```

I just want to add one log entry. I don't want EF to read all the entries already persisted in db.
How can I avoid this?

UPDATE1:

Well, I would not call it a solution but this approach works.

```
public static void LogChanges(ObjectContext context, string msg, int itemId, int userId, int logActionId, int logObjectId)
{
    context.ExecuteStoreCommand(
                "insert into log_history (object_id,action_id,item,info,user_id,date) values ({0},{1},{2},{3},{4},GETDATE())",
                logObjectId, logActionId, itemId, msg, userId);
}
```

Yet, I don't like this, cause it's a hack from the point of view of layers separation.
Here I'm to know storage column names. That's not OK.

UPDATE2:

This is what sql-profiler rturn upon AddObject call:

> exec sp_executesql N'SELECT  [Extent1].[id] AS [id], 
>   [Extent1].[object_id] AS [object_id],  [Extent1].[action_id] AS
>   [action_id],  [Extent1].[item] AS [item],  [Extent1].[info] AS [info],
>   [Extent1].[date] AS [date],  [Extent1].[user_id] AS [user_id] FROM
>   [dbo].[log_history] AS [Extent1] WHERE [Extent1].[user_id] =
>   @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=4

Sure, it asks not for all log entreis but why it makes a check for a given user id is a mystery for me.

Comment: What language is this? C#? If so, please add the relevant tag.

Comment: Did you run sql profiler on this? Is it actually getting the entities from the database?

Comment: Which version of Entity Framework are you using? Also can you pinpoint the line of code that causes it to pull all the entities

Comment: @Optional: EF 4.1, ctx.LogHistoryEntries.AddObject(he) after this call.

Comment: Code-First? Schema-First? if Code-First, can you post your context class?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Schema first.

Comment: It doesn't really look as it reads all the entries according to the sql. It filters on UserId. Is UserId set as key for this table? And if it is, does EF think it's a sql genereated key or a natural one?

Comment: My first thought, no primary/unique key on the table, or one that EF isn't aware of.

Comment: Does your context have an entity User with that user ID, and a navigation property to get the user's logged history? If so, is it possible that lazy loading is enabled and triggered by linking your new entry to that user?

Comment: @hvd Yes, user in the context already. And that's a great hint. Looks like you are right 100%. I use autogenerated POCOS with fixups in setters and there associated user.LogHystory is updated. I'll check it more thoroughly little later. Thanks a lot for you comment.

Answer (score 0):

Hvd is right. The reason for db roundtrips are generated POCOs with fixups and enabled lazy loading.